# Print the text typed HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a thing that shows the text a person is inputting into the text box
I tried the `.value` but it is not working,
here's the code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder="write a paragraph, press enter when done" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" onkeyup="weirdStuff()">
    <div id="div">your text will be here</div>
    <script>
        var text = document.getElementById("inputText");
        var textOutput = document.getElementById("div")
        //a useless line
        text.addEventListener("keyup",function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                text.onkeyup = function () {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
        function weirdStuff() {
            var stuff = textOutput.value;
            textOutput.innerHTML = stuff;
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

it returns undefined

Comment: Looks like a typo.  In your `weirdStuff` function you never get the value from the `input`.  Instead you try to get a value from the `div` (which doesn't have one) and write it back to the same `div`.

Comment: I got all mixed up trying to do this so I see the problem. Thank You to everyone who took time into responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet:

```js
var stuff = textOutput.value;
textOutput.innerHTML = stuff;
```

You are getting the value of `textOutput`, not `text`. Altering it to this should work:

```js
var stuff = text.value;
textOutput.innerHTML = stuff;
```

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use inline JS `on*` handlers (same as you don't use inline `style` attributes)
- Use an `"input"` listener for your *typing* - since a copy/paste is also an *input* event
- Finally you could use `Event.code` - since we're humans, not robots.

```js
const EL_text = document.getElementById("inputText");
const EL_output = document.getElementById("div");

EL_text.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {;
    EL_output.innerHTML = EL_text.value;
});

EL_text.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
  if (evt.code === "Enter") location.reload();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder="write a paragraph, press enter when done">
<div id="div">your text will be here</div>
```